# Are there APIs for skype for consumers rather than skype for business?

Tags: skype

I basically want to read and write Skype messages. I am not having Skype for business and it seems that Skype desktop Apis is ceased. Is there any way to push and read messages in Skype programmatically.

Send message to a user and receive messages from a user programmatically via APIs from their desktop application. Say a script runs in the background and push messages at a given time to a certain user.

Comment: Skype (normally also known as Skype for Consumer; SfC) and Skype for Business (SfB) are two different products. SfC is hosted by Microsoft and SfB is often hosted by companies or hosted in the cloud.Can you improve your question so that it is a little bit more clear which product you wish to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at these:
[Documentation](https://github.com/chrisss404/gnome-shell-ext-SkypeNotification/raw/master/docs/Skype%20Developer%20-%20Skype%20Desktop%20API%20Reference%20Manual.pdf)

and this [Gnoe Extension](https://github.com/chrisss404/gnome-shell-ext-SkypeNotification)